# Help me ask this confused question about the divergence of the harmonic series

Tags: sequences-and-series, soft-question, divergent-series, harmonic-numbers

I've struggled for a couple of weeks to figure out the question I really want to ask, but without any success, so I'm just putting out this rather confused question out in hopes that someone can help me.  The short version is:

> Why does the harmonic series diverge so quickly?

Before you jump to answer this (or to tell me it does not diverge quickly) please read the rest of the post.

Let's say as usual that $$\zeta(r) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty i^{-r},$$ where I will only be considering real $r$.  For $r=0$ the series obviously diverges and for $r=2$ it is well-known to converge.  In fact it converges if and only if $r>1$.

It's clear that as $r$ increases from $-\infty$ to $1$ the series $\zeta(r)$ diverges more and more slowly. One might naïvely think  the rate of divergence would gradually decrease to zero, after which there would be a region where the series converged.  But this isn't what happens.  Instead, after $r=1$ there is a drastic phase change in the behavior.  The behavior jumps suddenly from divergence to convergence, without ever achieving a rate of divergence slower than $\log n$.

But $\log n$ is not very slow.  Many series diverge more slowly.  ($\sum\frac1p$ for prime $p$, for example.)
If we imagine a space of possible behaviors of series, there is a largish region in this space that is avoided by the $\zeta$ series.

> What explains the gap in possible behaviors of $\zeta$?

Is there a way to formalize my idea of a a space $\mathcal B$ of possible series behaviors, and a topology on that space? If so, is anything understood about maps from the space of sequences to $\mathcal B$ and what the range of such a map can look like?

Is there any way to turn this into less muddled question?

Comment: Without talking about a possible topology of series behaviours, I'll just say that the series defining $\zeta(r)$ is just one family of series, so it's not surprising that it doesn't embody every possible rate of convergence/divergence. (I also find it interesting that you find the jump from $\log x$ divergence to convergence unnaturally large but not the jump from $x$-to-the-power divergence to $\log x$ divergence. Really there are gaps all over the place—for instance, none of them achieve $\sqrt x(\log x)^t$ divergence for any $t\ne0$.)

Comment: Are you considering "rate of divergence" in terms of big-O relations?

Comment: @aschepler I'm not sure my thinking about this was so specific.  Big-O is not a very fine-grained device for distinguishing rates of divergence.

Comment: @GregMartin All good points, thanks.

Comment: I agree with Greg Martin. It seems like a leap to assume that one series with a single "parameter" would achieve all possible classes of convergence/divergence

Comment: How is this behavior all that different from the geometric series $\sum r^{-n}$? As $r$ goes from $+\infty$ to 1 it converges more and more slowly, then at $r=1$ there is a change in its behavior, diverging for $r=1$ to $0$. What makes the change at $1$ "drastic" for the $\zeta$ series but not for the geometric series?

Comment: Whatever rate of divergence you had for $\zeta(1)$, you'd get the jump to convergence at $\zeta(1+\epsilon)$.  It's not like there is a "slowest possible rate of divergence" or anything like that.  If $f(n)\to \infty $ represents the partial sums of your series then $\log f(n)$ also goes to $\infty$, but a lot slower and there's a series that diverges at that rate as well.

Comment: Initially I thought the question you wanted to ask is something like the following: "Is there a mathematical formulation in which it both makes sense and is correct to say that most infinite series of real numbers that diverge to infinity do so more slowly than the harmonic series?" However, I think you're actually asking a question about something that depends on how certain collections of infinite series are parametrized (i.e. expressed), which seems not so much an issue that depends on intrinsic properties of series and collections of series, but instead on notation/description aspects.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro You are correct that I am not trying to ask the first question.

Comment: On Mathstodon, [Oscar Cunningham observes](https://mathstodon.xyz/@OscarCunningham/110855814072417539) that every real-parametrized family of series $S_r$ exhibits a gap like this one, so every family of series has a “drastic phase change” of this sort. Also see [Boundary between all convergent series on one side and divergent series on the other side](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/205471/).

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple notions to think about and in the end I suggest a way to think about your gap idea.

First, it is not clear why $\zeta(r)$ diverges more and more slowly. Divergence is a statement about non-existence of a limit. It's a yes/no and there is no in-between. You may be tempted to compare partial sums for equal $n$, but why do you choose equal $n$? That's an arbitrary (even though simplest) choice. You may as well compare the partial sums $S_r(\lfloor 1/(1-r)^n\rfloor)$ for different $r$. Therefore you take more terms for the "slower" series before you compare. It's a perfectly fine choice and shows that it's not easy to define a universal way of saying something is more divergent. Well, maybe the busy beaver function is more divergent as it diverges faster than any computable function.

At $r=1$ the series is still divergent and just because there is a simple expression $\ln x$ which is asymptotically only a constant away from the partial sum also does not have a special meaning. Maybe there are similar expression for $r<1$, maybe not... in any case according to the above argument it does not have a special meaning (unless you arbitrarily define how you choose to compare partial sums). There is no "gap" *below* $\ln n$ (it's all in the divergent range), but maybe above?

Now, here is a suggestion for how to understand what goes on between the divergent $\ln n+\gamma$ and the following convergent series for $r>1$. If you replace the summation by an integral, you can probably see that the sum is related to $\frac{1}{-r+1}n^{-r+1}$. For $r=1$ this would be $\frac10 n^0$ which for exactly zero fails to compute. Again, this is about existence and strictly yes or no. Indeed, the logarithm kind of behaves like the scaled zeroth power according to $\ln x=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} (x^\varepsilon-1)/\varepsilon$. So since the partial sums are related to $\frac{1}{s}n^s$ ($s=1-r$), there does not seem to be a gap between $s=0$ and $s>0$.

In that sense I don't really see a gap between $s=0$ and $s>0$, since the parameteric form of the partial sums is fixed to $\sim n^s$, and $\ln n$ "behaves" like $n^s$ with $s=0$.